# how do I solve : Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore]

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create this registration page using Firestore however while my app runs, I receive the following error and my Firestore does not get updated while my firebase does. I'm thinking it has to do something with my firebase.js as that where I invoked the method "doc". my codes is as follows

[image]

[image]

please help to advice how I can go about solving the problem as I am quite new to Javascript and Firestone. Thank you!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a document reference via `doc()` requires three arguments:

`doc(db, "collectionId", "docId")`

If you want to set the docId to be the user's ID try the following:

```
await setDoc(doc(db, "users", userId), {
    email: email
});
```

The full set of docs for setting/adding data can be found at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data